# let $n=x^2+y^2$, then all the prime factors of $n$ congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ occur to an even exponent

Tags: number-theory

let $n=x^2+y^2$, then all the prime factors of $n$ congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ occur to an even exponent. I know how to prove the other direction. But this direction seems to be more difficult, and I don't know much about number theory either...

Comment: I am sure this has come up (several times) before on MSE, so will just sketch a proof. Let $p$ be a prime factor of $x^2+y^2$  congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. If $p$ divides $y$, then it must divide $x$, and we are finished. So we may assume that $p$ does not divide $y$. Multiply the congruence $x^2+y^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ though by the square of the inverse of $y$ modulo $p$. We get $(xy^{-1})^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, which is impossible for a prime of the form $4k+3$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ divides $n=x^2+y^2$ and $\nu_p(n)$ is odd. If $p$ divides one number between $x$ and $y$ then it divides also the other one: in such a case we replace $n$ with $n/p^2$, $x$ with $x/p$ and $y$ with $y/p$. At last, we have that $p$ does not divide neither $x$ or $y$, and:
$$ x^2+y^2 \equiv 0\pmod{p}, $$
so $ x y^{-1} $ is a square root of $-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$. This gives a contradiction, since the Legendre symbol of $-1$ is:
$$ \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = (-1)^{2k+1} = -1. $$
This proves that, if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ divides $n=x^2+y^2$, then $\nu_p(n)$ is even.